# Timespan not accepting day in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, timespan

I have a MVC3 application in which i want to set a timespan to for example 2 days and 5 hours.
when i enter 02:05:00:00 it gives me the following exception:

```
System.OverflowException: SqlDbType.Time overflow.  Value '2.05:00:00' is out of range.  Must be between 00:00:00.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999.
```

When i enter 05:00:00 it correctly saves 5 hours into the database. according to MSDN timespan has a property for days. How do i correctly set the days?

Model:

```
public class ProductionTimeVM
{        
    [Required]
    public TimeSpan DefaultTime { get; set; }
}
```

In my view i just use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DefaultTime)
```

For my controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveProductionTime(ProductionTimeVM vm)
{           
   ProductionTime productionTime = new ProductionTime();
   productionTime.Default = vm.DefaultTime;

   //some more code
 }
```

Any idea's?

Comment: The error message shows a `.` where you should have a `:`.

Comment: yes, it does. It did suprise me too because i do enter a :

Comment: How are you passing the value to the DB?

Comment: I entered some code from my controller as an edit. I find it odd that just a time saves correctly but a time with a day throws an error

Comment: "**SqlDbType**.Time overflow." clearly indicates it's SQL server that causes the issues, and not ASP.net MVC.

Comment: Well, the exception message says explicitly that SqlDbType must have a value between 0:00:00 and 23:59:59, so clearly it doesn't accept 2 days...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably saving a TimeSpan value to column with [Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) datatype in database.  Time can only express a time of day, so you can't save TimeSpans larger than a day.

I use columns with bigint data type to store and retrieve ticks of TimeSpan. I would also like to know if there is a better alternative. This behavior is like default for some popular ORMs and it's misleading a lot of people I think.

Comment: +1 Not 'probably' but definitely because it's a `SqlDbType.Time overflow`.  Best thing to do will be to store the `Ticks` value in a `bigint`

Comment: hmm, you're right! how could i have not thought about that. I use EF and the column type does say "Time". What should i use instead?

Comment: I'm am testing your answer. But i'm almost sure it should work